# Mongodb authentication with nodejs and Monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I keep getting an error when attempting to query a collection on a mongodb that I have (appeared to) successfully connect to in my `app.js` file.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/test_db');

var app = express();

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
        req.db = db;
        next();
});
```

It connects and then in my router file:

```
/* users.js*/

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

   var params = req.body;
   var userid = params.userid;
   var pw     = params.password
   var db = req.db;
   var userdb = db.get('users');
   userdb.findOne({'userid' : userid}, function(e,user) {
     if (e) {
       console.log("error reading user doc ->");
       console.log(e);
       return;
     } else {
       ....
     }
  });
});
```

I get the following error after querying the collection:

```
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

Comment: The formatting monk(URL, {username,password}) was not working either. The problem was URI encoding the password to allow for special characters, when doing that you have to pass the object {uri_decode_auth: true}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the MongoDB docs for options:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/connecting/connection-settings/

You'll notice that username and password are not valid options. If you are connecting to test_db and your root user is in another database (lets say admin) you should use authSource: admin. You connection string would look like this:

```
var db = monk('user:pass@localhost:27017/test_db',{authSource:'admin'});
```

This was confusing me when I was trying to connect to to my database but my auth user was in another.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
var db = monk('localhost:27017/test_db', {
  username : 'USERNAME',
  password : 'PASSWORD'
});
or
var db = monk('USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/test_db');
```

Comment: Your second option works, but I couldn't make the first one to work.